# Fast on-the-fly image decompression

Tags: algorithm, image, compression, on-the-fly

I need to work with a good amount of 4-bit images. However, it's got to be for J2ME devices, which means great lack of memory. So, could you propose a compression algorithm that could decompress on the fly relatively fast and still have some reasonable degree of compression?

Comment: Could you share some of your results/experience?  I'm trying to achieve a similar result, however, I'm trying to store 1920x1080x3 frames without completely destroying a machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of your images. Simple run length encoding (RLE) might be enough and it's trivial to implement and very fast.

Comment: Delta-Packing or Golomb-Code would be fast too. Especially Golomb-Code can make good result.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm not sure RLE would be very efficient in my case because the images have a good amount of noise on the edges of the contours. I'll look up DP & GC.

Comment: I decided I'll use some more advanced preprocessing first and then I'll apply simple RLE for white/non-white as there's going to be a fair amount of white compare to all other shades of grey.

Answer (score 1):

For most practical uses, I would use an existing software compression package rather than implementing one myself.

Try [imagemagick covnert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php), it is fast, flexible and open source.

Comment: Yeah, but I need it done on the fly, i.e. fast. I don't think jpeg or png encoding would be adequate.

Comment: Can you pre-convert the images? What programming language are you using?

Comment: My main idea is to store the images in RAM in compressed form and to decompress them only when I use them. That's going to be relatively often though. I can of course, store them as RAW files, compressed in a zip file and then decompressed on the fly using a ZipInputStream, but access would most probably be too slow as ZIP is rather complex

Comment: @albus, first of all, get rid of "I don't think". Measure, find out if PNG is fast enough. Also, what are the images of? screenshot type of things or photos? And, what kind of compression levels and speeds are you looking for?

Comment: Well, the images are actually a 4-bit bitmap font containg great amount of glyphs (~35 000). As I'll be using it on J2ME devices (and some of them might have as little as 2MB of Java heap I'm looking for some kind of compression. I may not load the all at once, OK, but Chinese for instance uses loads of glyphs at the same time. And I'll be rendering those glyphs (i.e. copying and colouring) on a surface.

Comment: @albus Did you consider vector graphics (e.g. SVG) for the glyphs?

Comment: @Adam Matan, I did, but it would take quite a bit of time to render them, wouldn't it?